# Why does TimeSpan string formatting resolve into an Exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, string-formatting, timespan

I have the following line of code in my c# MVC2 Project:

```
string.Format(@"{0\:HH\:mm}", new TimeSpan(0))
```

This line is resulting in the following exception:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Can anybody tell me why? I'm using C#, asp.net, mvc2, and .net framework 4

Comment: Why do you escape the colons?

Comment: @RoyDictus: a colon is not a special format character so needs to be escaped. The first colon should not be escaped though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two problems. Firstly you should not be escaping the first `:`. This is necessary as a separator and should not be escaped.

The second is that `HH` should be `hh`.

This runs without errors:

```
string.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm}", new TimeSpan(0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really the problem. Also, I have a datetime format as "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", does this need the 'treatment' as well?

Comment: Reading the page oded linked (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) should tell you all you need to know. In this case that format string is valid since a `:` is actually a special format character that just means a colon. Why this difference exists I couldn't tell you though. :)

Comment: @Chris - I linked to `TimeSpan` format strings, which will be different from `DateTime` format strings... (for one, `HH` is valid for `DateTime`).

Comment: Oh true. That is a minor thinko (like a typo but in the thinking, not the typing). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx is the one for DateTime custom formats. Of most relevance is the difference on the "Any other character" section. DateTime says it is copied unchanged, TimeSpan says it is treated as a custom format specifier. Hence needing to escape for the latter but not the former.

Answer (score 3):

Your format string uses `HH` - it should be `hh`.

See [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) on MSDN.

Additionally, your first `:` shouldn't be escaped - it is part of the placeholder `0`, not a literal.

Together:

```
string.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm}", new TimeSpan(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use should use hh instead of HH.

Answer (score 0):

Check the specification here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx

You should use hh instead of HH, e.g.:

`var str = string.Format(@"{0:hh\:mm}", new TimeSpan(2,2,0));`